# Iterate JsonObject

Tags: javascript, iteration

Hi this is my JsonObject i want to iterate this and get the values of title elements class of header , Container and footer.

```
var jsonObj = [{
                                "Header": {
                                    "title": "Header",
                                    "element":"div",
                                    "class": "innerElements header",
                                    "id": "",
                                    "contenteditable":"true"
                                },
                                "Container": {
                                    "title": "Container",
                                    "element": "div",
                                    "class": "innerElements header",
                                    "id": "",
                                    "contenteditable":"true"
                                },
                                "Footer": {
                                    "title": "Container",
                                    "element": "div",
                                    "class": "innerElements header",
                                    "id": "",
                                    "contenteditable": "true"
                                }

                            }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by

```
for (var key in jsonObj[0]) {
  if (jsonObj[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + jsonObj[0][key].title);
  } 
}
```

Here id the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PD6Ng/) for this code.

For getting the inner elements from the object we have to extend the previous loop

```
for (var key in jsonObj[0]) {
  if (jsonObj[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " ---");
     for(innerKey in jsonObj[0][key]) {
        console.log(innerKey + " -> " + jsonObj[0][key][innerKey])         
      } 
    console.log("-----")  
  } 
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PD6Ng/1/) for above code

Comment: can you further extend this to get all values like class,elements,id, contenteditable? bcoz i want the code to be optimized otherwise i should write each line to get all the values

Comment: You can write another loop inside to get all the values